# Gettining java annotations using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm trying to spot, using reflection, the 'init' method that is annotaded with the @Override annotation (or with whatever annotation), but ok, heres my example, much simplified, ofcourse
Base class:

```
    public abstract class A
{
  public void init()
  {

  }
}
```

Then here the subclass:

```
    public class B extends A
{
  String bla;
  @Override
  public void init()
  {

  }

  public void init(String bla)
  {
    this.bla=bla;
  }
}
```

So the code i run to get the annotated method is this:

```
      public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ClassLoader c = Main.class.getClassLoader();

    try
    {
      Class<?> clazz = c.loadClass("correct.path.to.class.B");
      for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
      {
        if (method.getName().equals("init"))
        {
          System.out.println(method.getDeclaredAnnotations().length);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Both methods are correctly found but surprisingly, i get '0' twice when reading the length of the arrays containing the annotations, any idea whats wrong here?
The method `getAnnotation()` gives me the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for `@Override` and `RetentionPolicy`. Basically, the `@Override` annotation is not available at runtime, it's a source only annotation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Comment: so there is no way for me to get to that information at runtime...?

Comment: From the documentation: 'SOURCE Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.'